# Responsive design with css and html

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I am building a responsive form design for desktop and mobile devices.
I write a following code for that and it is working fine but it generates the problem when i resize window like mobile screen width the left and right margin space is little large. I want to minimize the space of left and right margin i tried a lot but fail can some one help me please

```css
.main_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e4e4e4;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main_container:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 100px 100px 0 100px;
  border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
}

.left_parent {
  float: left;
}

.left_child {
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-left: 0%;
  text-align: center;
}

.right_child {
  padding-right: 0%;
  padding-left: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  /*width: 40%;*/
}

.right_parent {
  float: left;
}

.left_uppper_text {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 130%;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-right: 3%;
  color: #847979;
}

.left_bottom_text {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 81%;
  color: #bbb;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main_child {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0% 0% 0% 27%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  /* border: 3px solid green; */
  padding: 10px;
}

.input_email {
  width: 67%;
  padding: 3% 17px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.input_button {
  max-width: 190px;
  min-width: 84px;
  padding: 3% 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 8px 0;
  background-color: rgba(245, 0, 83, 0.73);
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(245, 0, 83, 0.73);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(245, 0, 83, 0.73);
}
```

```html
<div class="main_container">

  <div class="main_child">

    <div class="left_parent">

      <div class="left_child">
        <span class="left_uppper_text"> Join over 20,2000 blog subscriber </span> <br>
        <span class="left_bottom_text"> We guarantee 100% customer satisfaction</span>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="right_parent">

      <div class="right_child">
        <input type="text" class="input_email">
        <button class="input_button">Subscribe</button>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Converted to snippet, can you better explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: add a media query for the screen size at which you want to reduce the margin. When the screen is that size (or smaller) the margins change. For that just declare your media query at the bottom and then redefine the element's margins.

Comment: thanks @Falk but dont have a knowledge about media query can you help me?

Comment: Sure. You can read up on the syntax and concept here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

As for what you want to do: @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
//replace 480 px with what you want.
    .element {
        margin: <new margin>
    }
}

Comment: Or see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can manipulate styles at any screen size using `@media` queries. In your case it might look something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px /* Mobile size */) {
   /* Element you want to style at this screen size */
   .element {
      margin: 5px; /* Or whatever style you want */
   }
}
```

You can read more about `@media` queries here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your project.